# android studio sdk manager not showing other packages

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-manager

when I use command line with `sdkmanager --list` it works and shows me everything but android studio is not showing me! why? what should I do to fix it?

[image]

[image]

---

#### *maybe useful notes*

- *I think this happend after updating to android Studio 4.2*

### Edit

---

#### I noticed a error occur when opening sdk manager

```
java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '.'
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.checkText(Formatter.java:2732)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.parse(Formatter.java:2708)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2655)
    at java.base/java.util.Formatter.format(Formatter.java:2609)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.format(String.java:2897)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.Storage.toUiString(Storage.java:269)
    at com.android.sdklib.devices.Storage.toUiString(Storage.java:252)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable.getDiskUsageMessages(SdkUpdaterConfigurable.java:385)
    at com.android.tools.idea.updater.configure.SdkUpdaterConfigurable.apply(SdkUpdaterConfigurable.java:299)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.ex.ConfigurableWrapper.apply(ConfigurableWrapper.java:182)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor.apply(ConfigurableEditor.java:309)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.SettingsEditor$5.apply(SettingsEditor.java:173)
    at com.intellij.openapi.options.newEditor.ConfigurableEditor$2.actionPerformed(ConfigurableEditor.java:59)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:270)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:117)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:190)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:235)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:233)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1063)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:711)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:438)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.doShow(DialogWrapper.java:1700)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1659)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsUtilImpl.showSettingsDialog(ShowSettingsUtilImpl.java:80)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.perform(ShowSettingsAction.java:54)
    at com.intellij.ide.actions.ShowSettingsAction.actionPerformed(ShowSettingsAction.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:282)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAwareWithCallbacks(ActionUtil.java:276)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:224)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.performAction(ActionPopupStep.java:214)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.ActionPopupStep.lambda$onChosen$2(ActionPopupStep.java:208)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performUserActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.lambda$dispose$16(AbstractPopup.java:1464)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2253)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.ifFocusEventsInTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:188)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.executeWhenAllFocusEventsLeftTheQueue(IdeEventQueue.java:140)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:36)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.AbstractPopup.dispose(AbstractPopup.java:1460)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.dispose(WizardPopup.java:158)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.dispose(ListPopupImpl.java:326)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.dispose(PopupFactoryImpl.java:304)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectNode.lambda$execute$0(ObjectNode.java:111)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeActionWithRecursiveGuard(ObjectTree.java:193)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectNode.execute(ObjectNode.java:71)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.ObjectTree.executeAll(ObjectTree.java:141)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:130)
    at com.intellij.openapi.util.Disposer.dispose(Disposer.java:120)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.WizardPopup.disposeAllParents(WizardPopup.java:261)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleNextStep(ListPopupImpl.java:461)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl._handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:415)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl.handleSelect(ListPopupImpl.java:361)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.PopupFactoryImpl$ActionGroupPopup.handleSelect(PopupFactoryImpl.java:324)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyMouseListener.mouseReleased(ListPopupImpl.java:526)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:298)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6654)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3345)
    at com.intellij.ui.popup.list.ListPopupImpl$MyList.processMouseEvent(ListPopupImpl.java:583)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6419)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5029)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4861)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:778)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:727)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:751)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:749)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:748)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:971)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:906)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$null$8(IdeEventQueue.java:452)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:744)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$9(IdeEventQueue.java:451)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:808)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:505)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

*at the bottom of android studio a red `!` appears*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was about **system locale** which was set to Persian.

After changing to **English United States** everything worked properly.

see: [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195754565)

Answer (score 0):

happened with me once after updating the app ,the problem gone after removing android studio and install latest version and remove .idea folder from the project

Comment: yes reinstalling is the last choice anyway..., Also I noticed that when I change something in sdkmanager the `apply` or `ok` buttons not working in android studio. seems like a bug.

Comment: tried remove  **.idea , .gradle** folder ?

Comment: Yes. Didn't help :(

Comment: Also please see the edit. It may help to solve

Comment: everything was about locale of my system. changing to `English United States` solved the problem